# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{6}{k(k+1)(k+3)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{6}{k(k+1)(k+3)}$$

I tried to simplify the sum and I got $\frac{2}{k}-\frac{3}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+3}$ but  I can't use this to simplify the terms.Also,I tried to amplify with $k+2$ and I got $$\frac{(k+3)-1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}=\frac{(k+3)}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}-\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}$$ but the terms also don't simplify.

Comment: It looks like your first simplified version can get you the answer. Just start writing out the first few terms and see what cancels out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{2}{k}-\frac{3}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+3}=\frac{2}{k}-\frac{2}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+3}=2\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)-\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+3} \right)$$

Comment: I did it!Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DaniVaja. Good to know and you are very welcome ! Remember the small trick since you will need it more than once. Cheers.

Comment: I don’t understand what the small trick does though

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{6 \over k\pars{k + 1}\pars{k+ 3}}} =
6\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}2\int_{0}^{1}\dd u_{1}\int_{0}^{u_{1}}\dd u_{2}\,
{1 \over \pars{k + u_{1} + 2u_{2}}^{3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
12\int_{0}^{1}\dd u_{1}\int_{0}^{u_{1}}\dd u_{2}\,\
\underbrace{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + u_{1} + 2u_{2}}^{3}}}
_{\ds{-\Psi''\pars{1 + u_{1} + 2u_{2}}/2}}\qquad
\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] = &\
-3\int_{0}^{1}\dd u_{1}\bracks{\Psi\, '\pars{1 + 3u_{1}} -
\Psi\, '\pars{1 + u_{1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-3\bracks{{1 \over 3}\,\Psi\pars{1 + 3u_{1}} - \Psi\pars{1 + u_{1}}}_{\ 0}^{ 1} =
-\
\Psi\pars{4} + 3\Psi\pars{2} + \Psi\pars{1} - 3\Psi\pars{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
3\ \underbrace{\bracks{\Psi\pars{2} - \Psi\pars{1}}}_{\ds{=\ 1}}\ -\
\underbrace{\bracks{\Psi\pars{4} - \Psi\pars{1}}}
_{\ds{=\ {11 \over 6}}}\ =\ \bbx{7 \over 6}
\end{align}

> Note that $\quad\left\{\begin{array}{rclcl}
> \ds{\Psi\pars{2}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\Psi\pars{1} + {1 \over 1}} &&
> \\[1mm]
> \ds{\Psi\pars{3}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\Psi\pars{2} + {1 \over 2}}
> & \ds{=} & \ds{\Psi\pars{1} + {3 \over 2}}
> \\[1mm]
> \ds{\Psi\pars{4}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\Psi\pars{3} + {1 \over 3}}
> & \ds{=} & \ds{\Psi\pars{1} + {11 \over 6}}
> \end{array}\right.$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Yes. That's quite true. Indeed, I was testing [Feynman Parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization#Formulas).